# c# datatypes and arrays

Tags: c#

I am creating an array for some monetary values.  I created the array as an integer and realized it needs to be decimal values.  When I change the variables to decimals and try and run it, I get "Cannot be implicitly converted from decimal to int."  I hover over the variables and they all appear to be decimals.  I remember in the past placing .00M after int's to force them to be a decimal, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.  Does this make sense to anyone else?

```
    //Global var
    Decimal lastIndexUsed = -1;
    Decimal[,] quarters = new Decimal[10, 5];
    string[] Branch = new string[10];

       //Calc button
            decimal Q1;
            decimal Q2;
            decimal Q3;
            decimal Q4;

            Q1 = Decimal.Parse(txtQ1.Text);
            Q2 = Decimal.Parse(txtQ2.Text);
            Q3 = Decimal.Parse(txtQ3.Text);
            Q4 = Decimal.Parse(txtQ4.Text);

            lastIndexUsed = lastIndexUsed + 1;
            quarters[lastIndexUsed, 0] = Q1;
            quarters[lastIndexUsed, 1] = Q2;
            quarters[lastIndexUsed, 2] = Q3;
            quarters[lastIndexUsed, 3] = Q4;
            Branch[lastIndexUsed] = txtBranch.Text;
```

The marked part is the first of many variables which error.

```
            Decimal row;
            Decimal col;
            Decimal accum;

            //Calculate

            for (row = 0; row <= lastIndexUsed; row++)
            {
                accum = 0;

                for (col = 0; col <= 3; col++)
                {
               ***     accum = accum + quarters[row, col];***
                }
                quarters[row, 4] = accum;
```

Comment: I have changed lastIndexUsed to an integer, still getting the same error.

Comment: Have also tried messing with "quarters" and changing it back to a int.

Comment: your row and col must be integers too

Comment: quarters[1,2] = 12.50; the value of your array elements are type Decimal. Row and Column must be integers as you can't address memory with fractions of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Decimal[,] quarters = new Decimal[10, 5];
```

The index numbers are integers.  You can't index by decimals.  The array contains decimals.

I changed it to this to get it to run and it prints 10.15 like you'd expect

```
`//Global var
    int lastIndexUsed = -1;
    Decimal[,] quarters = new Decimal[10, 5];
    string[] Branch = new string[10];

   //Calc button
        decimal Q1;
        decimal Q2;
        decimal Q3;
        decimal Q4;

        Q1 = Decimal.Parse("10.15");
        Q2 = Decimal.Parse("13");
        Q3 = Decimal.Parse("123.9877");
        Q4 = Decimal.Parse("321");

        lastIndexUsed = lastIndexUsed + 1;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 0] = Q1;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 1] = Q2;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 2] = Q3;
        quarters[lastIndexUsed, 3] = Q4;
        Branch[lastIndexUsed] = "hello";

        Console.WriteLine(quarters[0,0]);`
```

Comment: What your saying makes sense, but visual studio is not agreeing.  Your saying the only thing that needs to be changed is lastindexused?

Comment: Thanks! such simple errors always seem to trip me up,  First time writing c# in a while.

Answer (score 3):

`lastIndexUsed` is used as an array index and should remain an integer.

Comment: I have changed lastIndexUsed to an integer, still getting the same error.

Comment: All variables that are used as array indexes should be integers, including any ones that you didn't put in the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using an array of decimals, the indexer is still an integer.

```
Decimal lastIndexUsed;
```

should be

```
int lastIndexUsed
```